# Fidelity warning Rendering Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I have faced a problem when creating project in Android Studio 2.2

When trying to create xml layout, I get following warning:

[image]

When click to Show, I get the following error

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's just a warning, indicating that some details might not be rendered, not an error. You'll live, just press *"Ignore all fidelity warnings for this session"* so that you won't be disturbed with this warning again during your current work session.

Comment: It's a problem of the layout preview in Android Studio. It doesn't affect the final app at all.

Comment: I would like to know who voted you up! @MohammedAoufZouag because as you've said, some details might not be rendered! Now in android 7 the warning is no more joking around cause for real details not rendering in 7 and 6 downwards it's okay

Comment: It's not an error, You can continue your work fearlessly
It is just showing some of the components may not be accurate as you have set them in the xml file.
Just press ignore and you are good to go.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a warning, indicating that some details might not be rendered, not an error. It's a problem of the layout preview in Android Studio. It doesn't affect the final app at all. You can continue your work fearlessly It is just showing some of the components may not be accurate as you have set them in the xml file, but in reality, that view may possess some animation. Just press "Ignore all fidelity warnings for this session" so that you won't be disturbed with this warning again during your current work session.